# Need some help in making following function work

Tags: function, pine-script, undeclared-identifier

I wrote a test/practice function to do the macd for the given time frame as follows and it giving me errors

```
//@version=4
study(title="function test") 

src = close

//---macd, signal, histogram definitions

fastl = 12
slowl = 26
sigl = 9

fastMA = ema(src, fastl)
slowMA = ema(src, slowl)
macd = fastMA - slowMA
sig = ema(macd, sigl)
hist = macd - sig


//---function for macd calculations


//current time frame 

nt=timeframe.period


//function to automate calculating macd, signal and histogram for th nt or the current time frame.

omsh(nt) => 
    omf = security(syminfo.tickerid, nt, macd)
    osf = security(syminfo.tickerid, nt, sig)
    ohf = security(syminfo.tickerid, nt, hist)

// MACD plot

hline(0, '0 Line', linestyle=hline.style_solid, linewidth=1, color=color.gray)

plot(omf, color=color.blue)
plot(osf, color=color.red)
plot(ohf, style=plot.style_histogram, linewidth=1, transp=55)
```

Above function gives me the following errors

```
line 38: Undeclared identifier `omf`;
line 39: Undeclared identifier `osf`;
line 40: Undeclared identifier `ohf`
```

I just can't seem to figure out how to get around it.

They have been declared in the function omsh(nt), no?

And the function omsh(nt) has been run/executed/processed, with the input of the "nt", no?

Has the input nt been declared ok? I think I have done that correctly, but I could be wrong.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
omsh(nt) => 
    omf = security(syminfo.tickerid, nt, macd)
    osf = security(syminfo.tickerid, nt, sig)
    ohf = security(syminfo.tickerid, nt, hist)
```

You have declared those variables in local scope. That means, they are not visible outside of the function. That's why you are getting that error.

You don't need a function in your code. You can simply do:

```
omf = security(syminfo.tickerid, nt, macd)
osf = security(syminfo.tickerid, nt, sig)
ohf = security(syminfo.tickerid, nt, hist)
// MACD plot

hline(0, '0 Line', linestyle=hline.style_solid, linewidth=1, color=color.gray)

plot(omf, color=color.blue)
plot(osf, color=color.red)
plot(ohf, style=plot.style_histogram, linewidth=1, transp=55)
```

---

**Edit**: Due to OP's comment

A function can return multiple variables. So, you can work with local variables and just return them at the end.

```
omsh(nt) => 
    f_omf = security(syminfo.tickerid, nt, macd)
    f_osf = security(syminfo.tickerid, nt, sig)
    f_ohf = security(syminfo.tickerid, nt, hist)
    [f_omf, f_osf, f_ohf]
```

Then when you call this function, you should proivde three variables to get the return values:

```
[omf, osf, ohf] = omsh(nt)
```

Then simply plot those variables as you did before:

```
plot(omf, color=color.blue)
plot(osf, color=color.red)
plot(ohf, style=plot.style_histogram, linewidth=1, transp=55)
```

Comment: I understand I don't need a function. But like I said, I'm trying to learn how to write a function and this was a practice run. How would you fix it so that "function" runs as it's supposed to? I guess I have to declare it in side the function definition?  What I am trying to do is to use the `omf` `osf` and `ohf` as the outputs of the function.  And by doing so I learn how to write the functions and use the outputs of a function in another function etc.

Comment: Thank you Baris. I always tend to come across more problems after time I get my question answered on here. I've edited the original post after finding some issue in using the  array(?) tradingview referred to. Turning the output variables into a list(?) by putting them individually on their own lines changes the histogram and only histogram. How can that be?

Comment: Hi @boreddude, I suggest you undo your edit and ask a new question. We usually ask one question per post because if you and I keep editing, it would be difficult to follow for somone else who come here later. Heck, it is even difficult for me to follow now :)

Comment: ok. I'll do that. Thank you for the efforts btw. right now i'm battling if statement again and my brains is fried. i can't think anymore. i'll do it tomorrow